# How do I change the verbiage in card.io?

Tags: cordova, card.io

Can anyone tell me how to change the content in card.io screens? For example:

Postal Code => ZIP

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I can tell you!  You cannot change the content.  Sorry!  Are some users complaining that they don't know what a postal code is?

Comment: Yes. In U.S. they expect it to be called ZIP. This is a major problem for us right now. We might have to go with a different solution than card.io.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  We'll review this request and update accordingly.